# Html scroll: how to avoid it to "cut" my inner elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, firefox

this question is for an autocomplete drop down list I have to do that will fire while you're writing in an html textbox.

It basically consists of a div containing the suggestion elements, each of them being a div as well.

I got to the point where it's begining to work properly but now I added a vertical scroll to the containing div so you can limit the height of the drop down list, and I got the following behaviour:

If you use the scroll, it scrolls up or down in "pixels", so it cuts my elements making it all look anything but sleek.

I'd like to override the behaviour to go up and down one whole div element when you use the scroll. I don't even know how to google for this...

Anybody knows any useful resource about this or can give any tip as to where to start, if it's possible to override the scroll movement events or I should look into another direction?

Thanks a lot in advance

Note: I cannot use jquery autocomplete plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement your own scrollbar, using mouse events and updating positions manually.

Comment: Uff, I'm afraid there's going to be nothing easier than this... what a nightmare! thanks

Comment: Nothing says "thanks" like an upvote and an accepted answer! :)

Comment: Dear God, what have I become?

Comment: @DanielEarwicker Just as a joke the response would be: "a beggar?".

Answer (score 2):

Could you not tap into a 'scroll' event for that element (DOM 3 Events provides a scroll event for an element, not sure how supported it is), such that whenever the scroll position is changed, it calls a little routine of your own that adjusts the scroll position by rounding it to the nearest 'notch'?

Or, you could regularly poll for the scroll position and adjust it when it has moved.  [This scroll position](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:element.scrollTop#Example) seems fairly cross-browser.

Answer (score 2):

First:

Using your own scroll bar, make a scroll event handler. Here you could use an animation by `delta` ( it is found in `evt` ) on which you can set the `scrollTop` of the element yourself by the `offsetHeight` of your top or bottom visible element. Also if the div height does cut off an element just make the previous or next element a bit "higher" aka set it's height to push the cut off element up or down.

Second:

You could "patch" the div so only a few elements would be visible. and while you scroll you hide the top one and display the bottom one in a animation, without using s`crollTop` or `scrollHeight`.

Watch out for scroll event in Firefox. It has another name, but you can test it like this:

```
eventName = eventName === 'mousewheel' ? ((/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? "DOMMouseScroll" : eventName) : eventName;
```

Good Luck. If you need any help in about 2 days i will have it implemented, because i need one too.

Answer (score 0):

**This simply cannot be done**, there is no solution, period. One must live with this limitation.

Why is there no solution?

Because even if you implement your own scroll bar, you would still have to rely on scroll events, and these can be neither canceled nor prevented from bubbling to the body element. Really, they can't, you can call preventDefault() and stopPropagation() on them till the cows come home and they still bubble. This is a deliberate decision on the part of the standardizing body and browser implementors.

If scroll events were cancellable, EхpеrtEхchangе could prevent you from scrolling to the bottom of the page to see the answer ;) (don't worry, I used some Cyrillic letters in "EхpеrtEхchangе" so they don't get an indexable mention).

Comment: sorry but you are wrong. It can be done without preventDefault.